# Angular doesn't show me the data (problem json)

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, backend

I created an application where I did the backend using spring mvc and the frontend in angular.

The backend works (tested with Postman) but the frontend doesn't work well. In particular the latter does not show me the list of customers in the table.

Looking at the console I get the error:

Unexpected token c in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse () at XMLHtt…, text: "[{codeperson=BNCLSN43B12F205R, surname=Bianchi,…ZLLSRN85B52L219T, surname=Zollino, name=Sabrina}

message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/customerbuysproduct/customers-list"

Backend response:

```js
[
    {codeperson=BNCLSN43B12F205R, surname=Bianchi, name=Alessandro
    },          
    {codeperson=CRLMRC85M17I921J, surname=Carlini, name=Marco
    }               
]
```

Here I entered the code for the backend.

**BACKEND:**

Dao

```js
@Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> readViewListCustomerJson() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT codeperson,surname,name FROM customer");

    }
```

Controller

```js
@RequestMapping(value  = {"/customers-list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)    
    public String getString() {
        return customerDao.readViewListCustomerJson().toString();       
    }
```

**FRONTEND:**

app-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomerListComponent } from './customer-list/customer-list.component';  

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'view-customer', component: CustomerListComponent }  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```js
<div class="container p-3 my-3 bg-primary text-white">

  </div>
  
  <br>
  
  <div  class="container-fluid">  
        <ul class="navbar-nav">  
          <li class="nav-item ">  
            <a routerLink="view-customer" routerLinkActive="d-none" class="nav-link" class="btn btn-primary active" role="button" >Customers</a>  
          </li>   
                    
        </ul>  
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>  
    </div>
```

customers.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';  
import { Customer } from './customer';
  
@Injectable({  
  providedIn: 'root'  
})  
  
export class CustomerService {  
  
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/customersbuysproduct/';  
  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }  
  
  getCustomerList(): Observable<any> {  
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`+'customers-list');  
  }  
    
}
```

How can I fix this error?

**SCREENSHOT**
[image: Postman]

Comment: Please share the response of your backend as well as the code use in your frontend that triggers the error. Otherwise it'll be hard to help.

Comment: done. I entered everything

Comment: Is the sample response you've posed here of the backend identical to what you get on the Postman? Because that is not JSON. This is JSON `[{ "codeperson": "BNCLSN43B12F205R", "surname": "Bianchi", "name": "Alessandro" }]`

Comment: I've also noticed that your controller returns a `.toString()` try wrapping `ResponseEntity` of org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity instead. `return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);`. Assign the value of `readViewListCustomerJson()` to a variable called `response` first.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne yes exactly, from Postman I get that answer. I realized it wasn't in json format, but I'm not getting the answer in json

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne i tried as you said but i get HTTP error <status 406 - Not Acceptable. @RequestMapping(value  = {"/customers-list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)    
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getString() {
        Object response: customerDao.readViewListCustomerJson();  return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.OK)                                                                  
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below dependency in your code.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And modify the controller as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value  = {"/customers-list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
    public String getString() {
        return JSONArray.toJSONString(customerDao.readViewListCustomerJson());
    }
```

Comment: i tried as you said but i get HTTP error <status 406 - Not Acceptable

Comment: Try as above now

Comment: I tried, Su postman tells me: HTTP error <status 406 - Not Acceptable.
In Eclipse, Could not find acceptable representation.

Apart from the Controller I don't have to change anything else right?

Comment: Hey,  check your postman, did you enabled Accept as  multiple symbol / multiple symbol in header part

Comment: Check the above image

Comment: is already selected and the value is */* with asterisk

Comment: Can tou put screenshot of the postman call?

Comment: I put it in the post above

Comment: Ok give sometimes

Comment: help me because I'm going crazy -.-

Comment: try as above now. but for me, all look fines. are you return only JSON right? if you error still then ping me the whole strackTrace.

Comment: yes i just want to return the json.
Unfortunately it still does not work, but I send you the stacktrace and in addition I tried to see what that return was printing to me and I put the output here.

Comment: 1) stackTrace --> INFO: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
lug 06, 2021 3:39:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 69 ms
lug 06, 2021 3:39:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/customerbuysproduct] is completed
lug 06, 2021 3:41:03 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver resolveException
WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]

Comment: 2) System.out.println --> <200 OK OK,[{codeperson=BNCLSN43B12F205R, surname=Bianchi, name=Alessandro}, {codeperson=CRLMRC85M17I921J, surname=Carlini, name=Marco}],{}

Comment: I can see there is additional {} things end the response. If you provide the logs in screenshot then better. Due that additional {} causing the problem. And you are using spring boot right, why you don't try like jpaRepoitory with @Query.

Comment: And try print the output from service layer also

Comment: Unfortunately if I put the screenshot it doesn't fit everything, the line is cut. I made a copy / paste. However I am using spring mvc, no spring boot. I don't have a class of service

Comment: The line ends with {}. I didn't understand why

Comment: hey try as above

Comment: you're using some older version of spring MVC and this kind of issue is expected while returning the list of objects try as above and let see.

Comment: perfect now works great. Thank you so much and above all for the time. Thanks again.
I need a couple of little help. Would it be possible to get in touch? also by email if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234581/discussion-between-selvakumar-anushan-and-s-o-p-h-i-a).